# Setting Java Beans

Tags: java, javabeans

Hi I have a class that contains a list of bean methods such as setFoo and getFoo.

What I want to do is in another class set the value of a bean to equal a string value that I have.  The only issue is that I do not know how to:

1, Pass the string value to the bean.
2, How to apply the set/get method to the bean from a class outside the bean class.

This is my first time working with Java beans, hence the basic questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm note sure I understand the problem here, but here's a simple example of a bean class and another class which sets values in it and then uses them:

```
class Bean {
    private String foo;
    private int bar;

    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public int getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(int bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}

class Beanuser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bean bean = new Bean();
        bean.setFoo("foo");
        bean.setBar(807);

        System.out.println("bean foo: " + bean.getFoo());
        System.out.println("bean bar: " + bean.getBar());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mate, that explained it perfectly, I was unfamiliar with the syntax but after reading your answer and some more info on beans I figured it out.

Answer (score -1):

[Spring Expression Language](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) or [Java Expression Language (JEXL)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/) answer your need.